# Scala Map conversion

Tags: scala, dictionary

I'm a Scala newbie I'm afraid:
I'm trying to convert a Map to a new Map based on some simple logic:

```
val postVals = Map("test" -> "testing1", "test2" -> "testing2", "test3" -> "testing3")
```

I want to test for value "testing1" and change the value (while creating a new Map)

```
def modMap(postVals: Map[String, String]): Map[String, String] = {
  postVals foreach {case(k, v) => if(v=="testing1") postVals.update(k, "new value")}
}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You could use the 'map' method. That returns a new collection by applying the given function to all elements of it:

```
scala> def modMap(postVals: Map[String, String]): Map[String, String] = {
   postVals map {case(k, v) => if(v == "a") (k -> "other value") else (k ->v)}
}

scala> val m = Map[String, String]("1" -> "a", "2" -> "b")
m: scala.collection.immutable.Map[String,String] = Map((1,a), (2,b))

scala> modMap(m)
res1: Map[String,String] = Map((1,other value), (2,b))
```

Comment: Many thanks... I"m trying to get my brain to think functionally.  Slowly but surely ...

Answer (score 4):

Alternative to Arjan's answer: (just a slight change)

```
scala> val someMap = Map("a" -> "apple", "b" -> "banana")
someMap: scala.collection.immutable.Map[java.lang.String,java.lang.String] = Map(a -> apple, b -> banana)

scala> val newMap = someMap map {                                     
     |   case(k , v @ "apple") => (k, "alligator")            
     |   case pair             => pair            
     | }
newMap: scala.collection.immutable.Map[java.lang.String,java.lang.String] = Map(a -> alligator, b -> banana)
```

Comment: ahh nice.  I was trying something like this but couldn't get the syntax right.  Thanks.

Comment: @Benjamin, There was a slight mistake (in both my and Arjan's answers.) Corrected it now.

Answer (score 2):

even easier:

```
val myMap = Map("a" -> "apple", "b" -> "banana") 

myMap map {
   case (k, "apple") => (k, "apfel")
   case pair => pair
}
```